# Saving/Flushing Eclipse state without close IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there some way to save current workbench state without close the IDE?

It normally is not necessary, but I have already faced, many times, workbench freezes, that make me to kill the eclipse process, and lose all the workbench state (new packages, new imports, ...) I had before.

I would be great if I could flush workbench changes as easy as I save a class, or at least that such flush would take place automatically in times intervals.

Comment: It's confusing what you're really trying to accomplish. Workbench state doesn't have anything to do with the code in the files you're working on (packages, imports, etc). Workbench state is all about the state of Eclipse's UI, not the contents of your project(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 'Workspace Save Interval' configuration in the Eclipse Preferences on the 'General > Workspace' page.

Comment: Thanks greg-449, that's exactly what I was looking for! :)